# How to Remove Selected Items from Multiple List Boxes

Tags: c#

I have two listboxes and listbox1 selected index changed Event has the code :

```
      listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex
```

so when i click the item in one listbox , the Item with the same Index is selected automatically in another listbox, now i wanna remove these two items with a button . when i write the following code :

```
      listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
      listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
```

It Deletes only the Listbox1 SelectedItem , why not it is Deleting ListBox 2 selectedItem ??
I need Urgent Help / Response .I Would be very Greatful/ThankFul to all of YOU.
THANKS IN ADVANCE ,

Answer (score 3):

try to delete them in another order:

```
  listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
  listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

When you deleted the selecteditem at the first ListBox, SelectionChanged is firing and set SelectedItem of listbox2 into null.

Comment: +1, Either that, or unhook the index changed event, then delete things, then hook up that event again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to keep the selected index of each listbox in two separate variables and then delete each item by the index stored beforehand.